# Mongoose - embedded documents are saved as string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, pug

In my node app I have `designation` model with following `Schema`.

```
var DesignationSchema = new Schema({
    _id : ObjectId,
    designation : String
});
```

And this is embedded in `users` Schema.

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    fname:String,
    lname :String,
    email :String,
    password :String,
    designations : [DesignationSchema]
});
```

User can select one / many `designations` from `select` list. Below is my `jade` implementation for creating select list;

```
select(name="designations")
- for(var i = 0; i < designations.length; i++) {
    option(value="#{designations[i]}", name="designations[#{i}]") #{designation.designation}
- }
```

But these values are stored as `string` array instead of `DesignationSchema` array:

```
{
    designations : ["{designation:'Some Value' , _id : __DESIGNATION__ID}", "{designation:'Some Value' , _id : __DESIGNATION__ID}"]
}
```

**UPDATE**
I am pushing designations in following way in `expressjs` :

```
var newUser = new User(user.info);
if(user.designations && user.designations.length){
  for(var i =0; i < user.designations.length; i ++) {
    newUser.designations.push(user.designations[i]);
    //I have tried JSON.parse(user.designations[i]) but it raises error that says : 'Unexpected token d'
   //user.designations[i] object is something like : {designation:'Some Content', _id : __DESIGNATION__ID} 
   //IMPORTANT : the __DESIGNATION__ID is not inside single (') or double (") quotes. And I think this is the reason why JSON.parse is raising the error.
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you post code where you push entries into the designations array?

Comment: Could you make sure that user.designations[i] does not contain a string but a parsed json object?

Comment: @Saintedlama the `typeof` user.designations[i] is `string`. The value is : `{ designation: 'Contractor', _id: 52a494e789cf5d181a000001 }` . Please note the value of _id . I think it is failing the JSON.parse . But really don't know how to fix that.

Comment: OK, then the next question is where in the flow from browser to your code snippet does the content if designations[i] come from. Could you post all relevant code parts including express app setup?

Answer (score 0):

You can ommit the _id from DesignationSchema as Mongoose will add that for you itself. Make sure you JSON.stringify the data you POST/PUT/etc so that you are left with something you can parse.

You may also need to specify the content-type as application/json when you send the data back. This should allow you to avoid JSON.parse in your endpoint.